# Unable to understand mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, mod-jk

I am trying to call my sample Spring boot app from Apache using `mod_jk`. Everything is on my Windows 7 localhost. I know its easy with `mod_proxy` but I am sticking with mod_jk for learning purposes.

My Spring boot is up and running fine at `http://localhost:7200` I have used AJP port as 6200.

I want `Apache(running on 1111)` to redirect all the traffic from `http://localhost:1111/my-api` to `ajp://localhost:6200`

For example `http://localhost:1111/my-api/some/url` to `ajp://localhost:6200/some/url`
But Its redirecting to `ajp://localhost:6200/my-api/some/url`.I have verified in Spring Boot logs.

I have tried playing with some patterns but no luck. I don't know why its not working, Can someone help me understanding my mistake please.

I have mapped my jk_mount and re-write rule inside `httpd.conf` file as follows

```
JkWorkersFile ${SRVROOT}/conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile ${SRVROOT}/logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel debug

JkMount /my-api* myApiWorker

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /my-api/(.*) /$1
```

My worker.properties file

```
worker.list=myApiWorker

worker.myApiWorker.host=localhost
worker.myApiWorker.port=6200
worker.myApiWorker.type=ajp13
```

Comment: Maybe it's possible with `mod_rewrite` and the [\[P\]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) flag, but why don't you use `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_ajp`? See the [usage example](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html#usage) with `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`.

Comment: Currently I am learning Apache so trying to understand why its not working. I have tried `RewriteRule /(my-api)/(.*)$/ /$2 [P]` assuming that if I make a request to `/my-api/hello` it will rewrite it to `/hello`.But its making it `/my-api/hello` only no substitution happened.